# Is it fine to switch after the company retained you?

Tags: job-change

I am under a great confusion here. Recently I got an offer from a big MNC company and I was ready to switch but my present company retained me by offering double of what I was getting. During that period I gave an interview for a reputed MNC  bank and got selected there as well. 
Now it's only been a month since my present company retained me from switching. The work load is increasing as they say that I now have a package that demands this load.

Please suggest me that is it fine to make a switch both morally and career wise and if yes. What should be my answer to leave my present job?

Comment: You are free to switch the company cannot force you to work for them. Professionally its not the best move considering its only been a month. It sounds like you are staying in the same field, eventually if you move, it might hurt your chances in the future.  This choice has very little to do with "morality".

Answer (score 3):

Your current company has proved that they cannot be trusted; otherwise they would have paid you what you were worth without you having to show then a job offer.   Likewise they will never totally trust you as you tried to get a new job.

But if the take the job with the bank and it goes wrong, then don’t expect a helpful reference from your current job.

Whatever happen expect to have to work a lot harder or smarter, as when a company pays more, they expect more.

Comment: I disagree that the company isn't to be trusted.  The company's job is to pay you the lowest amount you are willing to take to do your job.  There are very few companies that will give you a raise (outside of annual reviews) without justification.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I strongly disagree, a company should work hard in order to have its employees feel good and welcome, if the mindset is "I'll screw them if I can", they'd better find a better company.

Comment: @Lohoris You use "should", but my experience is that companies "have" brought in new hires at market rates while keeping previous employees at lower payscales.  In fact, at one job, I was promoted to manager of a development team, and made less than 5 of my 6 direct reports for over a year.  That's why changing jobs is important to reset your salary to market levels every few years.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that once you have showed your wish to leave your current company, the best thing to do is leaving, because they won't trust you anymore.

They won't forget that you were the one wanting to go away and when they will have to cut some positions, you will be one of the first to be cut.

Also, you should be ethical when you are treated accordingly. Behaving in a correct way with someone who is not doing the same is useless.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a valid reason to take the other job, if that's what you want.

My current employer recently offered me a raise to stay after I'd gotten an offer elsewhere, and I did, but accepting their offer to retain me didn't mean anything more than passing on the job offer I had at that moment.  If I'd received a better offer later, I'd have taken it, and if I receive a better offer now, I'll take it.  I didn't agree or say that I'd stay for any period or time, nor did they make the offer contingent on my staying for any period of time, so the deal was simply that I'd stay, at that point in time.

If they tried to switch up the terms of my retention after the fact, I definitely would have left, and it sounds like that's what's happened to you.  Can't be sure without knowing all the details, but it sounds like they retained you, and then dumped more work on you in exchange for the pay raise, without telling you upfront that they were going to do so.

Therefore, I would view this as the terms of the arrangement having changed - you stayed for more money, on the assumption the job and workload would be the same.  With them changing their part of the deal, you have the right to change your part, and accept the other job offer, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a boss that got you double your rate, then you leave shortly thereafter, you'll most likely make him look bad and in return receive a poor reference if you ever need one in the future.

I went this route with a previous employer.  I felt I was underpaid, but I like the job/people, so I went out, interviewed, and got an offer that was at market rate.  I used that offer as leverage to get more money at the current job that I liked.  There were no hard feelings between me and the boss, even though he had to go up two levels to get the raise approved, because I stayed on and was a productive employee for another year or so before moving to a new city.

If someone gets you a raise, whether at great or little cost to that person, and you decide to take the raise instead of the new job, you should stay with that company for a little while unless there are other reasons you can cite, like workload or responsibility changes.